# Yarn Packager Include Folders and Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, yarnpkg

I'm working on a desktop application with JavaScript, [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/) and [Electron](https://electronjs.org/). And I'm using yarn package manager. I need to add some folders and json files into the package which is created via `yarn package` command. These are the additional files and folders which're not creating with code.

How can I include them?

**Edit**: I'm using [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate). So when I run `yarn package` these commands are running:

```
yarn build && electron-builder build --publish never
```

I want to copy these additional files into release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe someone needs that, I found the solution:

You should set your additional folders/files to `package.json` as `extraResources` under the `build` object:

```
"extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "node_modules/regedit/vbs",
        "to": "regedit/vbs",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      },
      {
        "from": "app/assets",
        "to": "../app/assets",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      },
      {
        "from": "app/temps",
        "to": "../app/temps",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
```